# Next positive date in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

| p_date | Qty | Available | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/04/2021 | -1 | 2 | Debit |
| 11/08/2021 | -1 | 1 | Debit |
| 11/09/2021 | -1 | 0 | Debit |
| 11/15/2021 | -1 | -1 | Debit |
| 11/17/2021 | -5 | -6 | Debit |
| 11/18/2021 | -50 | -56 | Debit |
| 11/18/2021 | -3 | -59 | Debit |
| 11/18/2021 | -1 | -60 | Debit |
| 11/20/2021 | 10 | -50 | Credit |
| 11/21/2021 | 100 | 50 | Credit |
| 11/21/2021 | -1 | 49 | Debit |
| 11/24/2021 | -62 | -13 | Debit |
| 11/26/2021 | -4 | -17 | Debit |
| 11/30/2021 | -1 | -18 | Debit |

I have a table like above where the 'Qty' could be positive number or negative number depending on whether the 'Type' column is 'Debit' or 'Credit'.

I want to write a SQL query to add a extra column to the table like below to show next positive p_date when the 'Available' column will become positive.

Note: when the 'Available' already column is positive number, the 'Next Positive p_date' column will show the 'p_date' column.

| p_date | Qty | Available | Type | Next Positive p_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/04/2021 | -1 | 2 | Debit | 11/04/2021 |
| 11/08/2021 | -1 | 1 | Debit | 11/08/2021 |
| 11/09/2021 | -1 | 0 | Debit | 11/09/2021 |
| 11/15/2021 | -1 | -1 | Debit | **11/21/2021** |
| 11/17/2021 | -5 | -6 | Debit | **11/21/2021** |
| 11/18/2021 | -50 | -56 | Debit | **11/21/2021** |
| 11/18/2021 | -3 | -59 | Debit | **11/21/2021** |
| 11/18/2021 | -1 | -60 | Debit | **11/21/2021** |
| 11/20/2021 | 10 | -50 | Credit | **11/21/2021** |
| 11/21/2021 | 100 | 50 | Credit | 11/21/2021 |
| 11/21/2021 | -1 | 49 | Debit | 11/21/2021 |
| 11/24/2021 | -62 | -13 | Debit | **12/05/2021** |
| 11/26/2021 | -4 | -17 | Debit | **12/05/2021** |
| 11/30/2021 | -1 | -18 | Debit | **12/05/2021** |
| 12/05/2021 | 80 | 62 | Credit | 12/05/2021 |

Comment: Please do not spam tags, add only the tag of the DBMS you actually use, because they all different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make LAG() ignore NULLS in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105702/how-to-make-lag-ignore-nulls-in-sql-server)

Comment: @rain_maker Which specific RDBMS are you using(MySQL/Postgresql/Snowflake)?

Comment: I’m using Snowflake.

Comment: @Lukasz is it possible to keep track of the quantities that are used. Like below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69865551/next-positive-date-in-sql-with-keeping-tracking-of-quantity?noredirect=1#comment123499511_69865551

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be achieved with `LEAD` windowed function:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Available >= 0 THEN p_date
               ELSE LEAD(CASE WHEN Available > 0 THEN p_date END) IGNORE NULLS
                    OVER(ORDER BY p_date)
          END next_p_date
FROM tab
ORdER BY p_date;
```

How it works: CASE expression nullifies p_date if Available is lower than 0 and IGNORE NULLS skips that p_date(effectively finding the first p_date with positive available)